# Accessing the foreign-key also with group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database schema:

```
Book(ISBN, Name, Genre)
Details(ISBN, Price, Total_pages)
```

Where `ISBN` is the **primary-key** for `Book` table, and **foreign-key** for the `Details` table.

Now I need to find the **most expensive book in each genre**. I have tried like this:

```
SELECT
        Genre
        ,MAX (Price) AS MAX_Price
    FROM
        Book
        ,Details
    GROUP BY
        Genre
;
```

But it gives me wrong ans. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your query finds the *highest price*, not the *most expensive book*.  The most expensive book would presumably have a title or ISBN or something that identifies the *book*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query.It may helps you.

```
SELECT
    Book.Genre
    ,MAX(Details.Price) AS MAX_Price
FROM
    Book
    INNER JOIN Details
    ON Book.ISBN = Details.ISBN
GROUP BY
    Book.Genre
;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use join syntax to tell database which relation you want when you select multi table

```sql
select Genre,Max(Price) as MAX_Price
    from Book
    -- point relation condition
    left join Details on (Book.ISBN=Details.ISBN)
    group by Genre
```